# Ordenar array por palabras repetidas en PHP

Tags: php, laravel, array

Tengo un array en PHP (laravel) con palabras extraidas de ciertos tweets. Necesito poder crear una lista o tabla donde se muestre una palabra y la cantidad de veces que se repite en ese array. Es decir, si la palabra es "hola" y se repite 6 veces, que aparezca la palabra y al costado la cantidad de veces que se repite. Solo eso.

Comment: No veo el código que has intentado.

Answer (score 0):

no se si es la forma mas eficiente de hacerlo pero yo lo haría con una función así:

```
function palabras($str) {
$palabras = explode(" ", $str);
$palabrasArray = [];
$contador = [];
foreach($palabras as $palabra) {
  if(in_array($palabra, $palabrasArray)) {
    array_push($palabrasArray, $palabra);
    $contador[$palabra]++;
  } else {
    array_push($palabrasArray, $palabra);
    $contador[$palabra] = 1;
  }
}
arsort($contador);
return $contador;
  }
  $string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";

  palabras($string);
```

---

Olvidaba que es laravel, 
simplemente crea lo mismo pero en un metodo

```
public function contarPalabras($str) {
  ...
}
```

Y lo llamas asi:

```
$this->contarPalabras($cadenaOTweet);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP tiene muchas funciones para manejar arrays que facilitan enormemente cualquier trabajo, te dejo una alternativa:

```
//palabras a contar
$words=['hola','adios'];

//frase a usar para contar palabras
$frase='hola gato, hola perro, hola sol, adios nube, adios';

//eliminamos cualquier caracter que no sea una letra
$frase=preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]/", '', $frase);

//array_count_values hace el trabajo facil resumiendo el total
//de apariciones por cada elemento de un array .   
$w=array_count_values(explode(' ',$frase));

var_export($w);
```

**Resultado contabilización**

```
array ( 'hola' => 3, 'gato' => 1, 'perro' => 1, 'sol' => 1, 'adios' => 2, 'nube' => 1 )
```

**Filtro de palabras que me interesan buscar**

```
//y finalmente nos quedamos con la interseccion de ambos arrays    
$matches = array_intersect_key($w, array_flip($words));

var_export($matches);
```

**Resultado**

```
array ( 'hola' => 3, 'adios' => 2 )
```

**Función y ejemplo de uso**

```
function contarPalabra($frase,$filtro){
    $w=array_count_values(explode(' ',preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]/", '', $frase)));
    return array_intersect_key($w, array_flip($filtro));
}

$frase='hola gato, hola perro, hola sol, adios nube, adios';

$cuenta = contarPalabra( $frase, ['gato']);

var_export($cuenta);
```

**Pruebas**

```
$words=['hola','adios'];
$frase='hola gato, hola perro, hola sol, adios nube, adios';

echo '<hr>';
$cuenta = contarPalabra( $frase, ['hola']);
var_export($cuenta);

echo '<hr>';
$cuenta = contarPalabra( $frase, ['perro']);
var_export($cuenta);

echo '<hr>';
$cuenta = contarPalabra( $frase, ['adios']);
var_export($cuenta);
```

**Resutados**

```
array ( 'hola' => 3, )
array ( 'perro' => 1, )
array ( 'adios' => 2, )
```

En el sitio de PHP.net puedes encontrar todas las funciones y definiciones para manejo de arrays.
http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: Lo ideal sería esperar que la persona nos comparta algo de código para ayudar.